# Checking variables exist before building an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I am generating a string from a number of components (title, authors, journal, year, journal volume, journal pages). The idea is that the string will be a citation as so:

```
@citation = article_title + " " + authors + ". " + journal + " " + year + ";" + journal_volume + ":" + journal_pages
```

I am guessing that some components occasionally do not exist. I am getting this error:

```
no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

Is this indicating that it is trying to build the string and one of the components is `nil`? If so, is there a neat way to build a string from an array while checking that each element exists to circumvent this issue?

Comment: if doesn't exist what you want to output ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easier to use interpolation

```
@citation = "#{article_title} #{authors}. #{journal} #{year}; #{journal_volume}:#{journal_pages}"
```

Nils will be substituted as empty strings

Comment: This works beautifully. Many thanks. Will accept when the timer allows me too....cheers Pal.

Answer (score 1):

```
array  = [
           article_title, authors ,journal, 
           year, journal_volume, journal_pages
         ]

@citation = "%s %s. %s %s; %s:%s" % array
```

Use [`String#%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-25) format string method.

**Demo**

```
>> "%s: %s" % [ 'fo', nil ]
=> "fo: "
```

Comment: This also works but for reasons I haven't explained above, the solution of Mohammad AbuShady fits better with my needs. Many thanks Arup.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you presumably are doing this for more than one article, you might consider doing it like so:

```
SEPARATORS = [" ", ". ", " ", ";", ":", ""]
article = ["Ruby for Fun and Profit", "Matz", "Cool Tools for Coders", 
           2004, 417, nil]

article.map(&:to_s).zip(SEPARATORS).map(&:join).join
  # => "Ruby for Fun and Profit Matz. Cool Tools for Coders 2004;417:"
```